# Apache Flink -TumblingProcessingTimeWindows - Incorrect calculation Start-End

Tags: apache-flink

it's very simple example:env.keyBy(value -> (...)) .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(24))).addSink();
................

```
public Collection<TimeWindow> assignWindows(){
final long now = context.getCurrentProcessingTime();
long start = TimeWindow.getWindowStartWithOffset(now, offset, size);
```

// the value "now" is correct = 1603379120043 (Date in your timezone*: 10/22/2020, 12:05:20 PM GMT-0300 (-03))

// the value "start" is 1603324800000 (Date in your timezone*: 10/21/2020, 9:00:00 PM GMT-0300 (-03) : ???!!!!!
// I should started yesterday ???

// As the result:

```
public TimeWindow(long start, long end) {
        this.start = start;  //1603324800000 - Date in your timezone*: 10/21/2020, 9:00:00 PM GMT-0300 (-03) 
        this.end = end;    //1603411200000 - Date in your timezone*: 10/22/2020, 9:00:00 PM GMT-0300 (-03)}
```

So, my job with 24h TumblingProcessingTimeWindows starting now at 10/22/2020, 12:05:20 PM will be finished today  at 9:00:00 PM === 9 hours instead of 24 hours

Some solutions, please ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Flink's windows are aligned to the epoch, not to the time when they are created. So a 24 hour window will end at midnight UTC.

You can use the optional offset parameter to shift the window boundaries.